# Count unique names of 2 different columns in pandas pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with names appearing in two columns (player1_name & player2_name may have the same players in different rows):

| PLayer1_name | player2_name | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kasparov | B.Fisher | Paris |
| Caruna | Wesley.So | Tokyo |
| Nakamura | Kasparov | S.Petersburg |
| Caruna | Nakamura | New York |

If This was the table, what I would like to get is:

```
Kasparov 2
Caruna 2
Nakamura 2
Wesley.So 1
B. Fisher 1
```

Basically, value_counts() of 2 combined columns. I'm guessing is pretty simply but I can't seem to get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
out=df.melt(None,['PLayer1_name','player2_name'])['value'].value_counts()
```

OR

```
out=df[['PLayer1_name','player2_name']].stack().droplevel(1).value_counts()
```

output of `out`:

```
Kasparov     2
Nakamura     2
Caruna       2
Wesley.So    1
B.Fisher     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True` may perform better as it does not require reshaping:

```
values, counts = np.unique(df[['PLayer1_name', 'player2_name']],
                           return_counts=True)
s = pd.Series(counts, index=values).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

`s`:

```
Caruna       2
Kasparov     2
Nakamura     2
B.Fisher     1
Wesley.So    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Some Timing Information:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'PLayer1_name': {0: 'Kasparov', 1: 'Caruna', 2: 'Nakamura', 3: 'Caruna'},
    'player2_name': {0: 'B.Fisher', 1: 'Wesley.So', 2: 'Kasparov',
                     3: 'Nakamura'},
    'Place': {0: 'Paris', 1: 'Tokyo', 2: 'S.Petersburg', 3: 'New York'}
})
```

This Answer:

```
def fn(df):
    values, counts = np.unique(df[['PLayer1_name', 'player2_name']],
                               return_counts=True)
    return pd.Series(counts, index=values).sort_values(ascending=False)

%timeit fn(df_)
640 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[Anurag Dabas's melt option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68213670/15497888):

```
def fn2(df):
    return df.melt(
        None, ['PLayer1_name', 'player2_name']
    )['value'].value_counts()

%timeit fn2(df_)
2.05 ms ± 203 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[Anurag Dabas's stack option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68213670/15497888):

```
def fn3(df):
    return (
        df[['PLayer1_name', 'player2_name']].stack()
            .droplevel(1).value_counts()
    )

%timeit fn3(df_)
1.32 ms ± 51.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'd always go for a numpy option such as this one, not only for speed but also because it's intuitive what it's happening behind the sheets.

Comment: There are always pros and cons to every approach. But in this case, I think `numpy` is best.